# How to colorize only one of the three branches in a game tree?

Tags: color, trees

I am using Osborne's egameps package to create a game tree of an extensive game. How could I colorize only the right branch of the tree branch in the first movement as red. I attempted to use `\iiib[][][linecolor=red]{$X$}{$Y$}{$Z$}`, as I deal with the two-branch situation, but it doesn't colorize anything, and disturbs the entire game tree. What should I do?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pstricks,egameps} 
\usepackage{pst-3d}% Above two packages are for extensive games

\begin{figure}[htb]%
\hspace*{\fill}%
\begin{egame}(810,290)
\putbranch(360,250)(3,1){360}
\egalvshift=5
\iiib[][][linecolor=red]{1}{$X$}{$Y$}{$Z$}
\putbranch(0,130)(1,1){90}
\egalhshift=18
\iib{2}{$Y$}{$Z$}[$0,2$][$1,1$]
\putbranch(360,130)(1,1){90}
\egalhshift=18
\iib{2}{$X$}{$Z$}[$0,2$][$2,0$]
\putbranch(720,130)(1,1){90}
\egalhshift=18
\iib[linecolor=red][]{2}{$Z$}{$Y$}[$1,1$][$2,0$]
\end{egame}
\hspace*{\fill}%
\caption[]{An extensive game.}\label{f:se1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. Could you extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) (i.e. the preamble)? Would you consider using another package to do this kind of thing? A lot of the things I see in the manual can be done with TikZ/`forest`. How do you diagrams look like?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel There were only two packages (actually only the \usepackage{pstricks,egameps} one) is used in this code, as shown in the updated code part. Could you show me how to use TikZ to colorize only one branch in the first move? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A version after receiving additional information.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{egameps}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[\htb]%
\hspace*{\fill}%
\begin{egame}(810,290)
\putbranch(360,250)(3,1){360}
\egalvshift=5
%\iiib[][][linecolor=red]{1}{$X$}{$Y$}{$Z$} 
\iiib{1}{$X$}{$Y$}{$Z$} 
\ib[linecolor=red]{1}{} 
\putbranch(0,130)(1,1){90}
\egalhshift=18
\iib{2}{$Y$}{$Z$}[$0,2$][$1,1$]
\putbranch(360,130)(1,1){90}
\egalhshift=18
\iib{2}{$X$}{$Z$}[$0,2$][$2,0$]
\putbranch(720,130)(1,1){90}
\egalhshift=18
\iib[linecolor=red][]{2}{$Z$}{$Y$}[$1,1$][$2,0$]
\end{egame}
\hspace*{\fill}%
\caption[]{An extensive game.}\label{f:se1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but what I need is only making the right branch(or anyone branch) of the three branches in the first move in red, rather than all of them in red. @Przemysław Scherwentke

Comment: @user39691 I hope that a new version is closer to your expectations.

Comment: It works! Very nice! Thank you very much! And an additionally question: if I want the left or the middle branch to be in red, what can I do? I tried to move the \ib[linecolor=red]{1}{} to different positions around \iiib{1}{$X$}{$Y$}{$Z$}, or used \iib[linecolor=red]{1}{}, but non of them works... @Przemysław Scherwentke

Comment: @user39691 Alas, \iiib has not three style parameters, so I am afraid that your tree should be build of trees with one or two branches (the trick with making a node initial again).

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the `egameps` package is the best `pstricks`-based tool to draw game trees.
Another solution is to use the package [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame), which is based on `TikZ`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[line width=.8pt]
\xtdistance{15mm}{40mm}
\istroot(0){1}
  \istb{X}[al]
  \istb{Y}[r]
  \istb[draw=red]{Z}[ar]
  \endist
\xtdistance{10mm}{20mm}
\istroot(1)(0-1){2}
  \istb{Y}[al]{0,2}
  \istb{Z}[ar]{1,1}
  \endist
\istroot(2)(0-2)<135>{2}
  \istb{X}[al]{0,2}
  \istb{Z}[ar]{2,0}
  \endist
\istroot(3)(0-3){2}
  \istb[draw=red]{Z}[al]{1,1}
  \istb{Y}[ar]{2,0}
  \endist
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is probably possible to get the last level (at least for a simple tree) from `forest` directly but for now, you need to give it manually.

The `egame` style sets a few styles only for this tree. Comments in code.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{
  edge label style/.style={text=.,font=\scriptsize,inner sep=+.1667em,midway,yshift=+1mm}}
\forestset{
  label position/.code=\forestoset{label position}{#1},
  last level/.initial=-1, % set it!
  egame/.style={
    /tikz/every label/.append style={inner sep=+.1em,font=\scriptsize},
    el/.style={% short for "edge label"
      if={n()<=\forestOve{\forestove{@parent}}{n children}/2}
        {edge label={node[edge label style, left] {$##1$}}}
        {edge label={node[edge label style, right]{$##1$}}}},
    for tree={
      label position=above,% default label position
      if={level==\pgfkeysvalueof{/forest/last level}}{% last level?
        delay={content/.expanded={$\forestov{content}$}}% put content in math
      }{
        node options={% a black dot
          shape=circle,
          fill, draw, inner sep=+0pt,
          minimum size=+2pt},
        delay={
          label/.expanded=% level as label
            {\forestove{label position}:\noexpand\pgfmathprint{int(level()+1)}}}
      }}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} last level=2, egame
[
  [,        el=X, 
    [{0,2}, el=Y]
    [{1,1}, el=Z] ]
  [,        el=Y, label position=above right
    [{0,2}, el=X]
    [{2,0}, el=Z] ]
  [,        el=Z, edge=red
    [{1,1}, el=Z, edge=red]
    [{2,0}, el=Y] ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A recommended solution with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-tree}
\psset{labelsep=5pt,radius=3pt}

\def\red{\ncline[linecolor=red]}
\def\lbl#1#2{\nput{#1}{\pssucc}{$#2$}}% \nput will not update the bounding box!

\begin{document}
\psTree{\TC*~[tnpos=a]{1}}
    \psset{levelsep=1}
    \psTree{\TC*\lbl{135}{2}\tlput{$X$}}
        \Tp*~{$0,2$}\tlput{$Y$}
        \Tp*~{$1,1$}\trput{$Y$}
    \endpsTree
    \psTree{\TC*\lbl{45}{2}\trput{$Y$}}
        \Tp*~{$0,2$}\tlput{$X$}
        \Tp*~{$2,0$}\trput{$Z$}
    \endpsTree  
    \psTree{\TC*[edge=\red]\lbl{45}{2}\trput{$Z$}}
        \Tp*[edge=\red]~{$1,1$}\tlput{$Z$}
        \Tp*~{$2,0$}\trput{$Y$}
    \endpsTree  
\endpsTree
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Notes

- `\nput` can be used to label a tree node. Unfortunately, it will not update the bounding box. It should not be used.
- `~[]{}` is another syntax to label a tree node. It will update the bounding box. But, unfortunately, `tnpos` can only accept 4 preset values: `a` for above, `b` for bottom, `l` for left, and `r` for right. It does not support an arbitrary angle such as `45` degree. A sad news!

Comment: 'A recommended solution': by whom? Or just in the sense that all solutions are recommended by those who post them?