# Does \pslistplot support option polarplot=true?

Tags: pstricks

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.5}
\begin{pspicture}(-8.5,-8.5)(14,9)%
\psset{linewidth=.35mm,plotstyle=curve,polarplot=true}
%
\psplot[plotpoints=200]{0}{720}{8 2.5 x mul sin mul}
%
%the same (?) with \pslistplot
\pstVerb{/mylist {/x exch def x DegtoRad 8 2.5 x mul sin mul x 720 lt {x 3.6 add mylist} if} def }
\pslistplot[linecolor=blue]{0 mylist} % 0 mylist => 0 0 0.0628318489 1.25147569 ... 4*Pi 0.0 
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Obviously, the graphs generated by `\psplot` and `\pslistplot` are not the same;`\pslistplot` doesn't seem to acknowledge the `polarplot` option.

[image]

Comment: The documentation says: *With the option `polarplot=false|true` it is possible to use `\psplot` in polar mode* -- Does it answer your question.

Comment: @Marco: Thanks. Indeed, that answers the question. It's a pity, nevertheless.

Comment: Indeed. Maybe you can send a feature request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\pstVerb{/mylist {
  /x exch def 
  8 2.5 x mul sin mul 
  x cvi 360 mod PtoC  
  x 720 lt {x 3.6 add mylist} if} def }
```

or wait for the next update.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.5}
\begin{pspicture}(-8.5,-8.5)(9,9)%
\psset{linewidth=.35mm,plotstyle=curve,polarplot}

\psplot[plotpoints=200,linewidth=3pt,linecolor=red,algebraic]{0}{13.5}{8*sin(2.5*x)}
\pstVerb{/mylist {/x exch def x 8 2.5 x mul sin mul x 720 lt {x 3.6 add mylist} if} def }
\pslistplot[linecolor=white,linewidth=1pt]{0 mylist}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

By the way: using the PSTricks mailing list makes more sense.

[image]

Comment: ... but you don't earn rep there :). I see. `PtoC`, very smart.

Comment: I used `\nput` [here (click)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144139/19356) instead but according to the documentation, `\nput` will not consider the bounding box so it is a bad choice.

Comment: Why can `algebraic` option *NOT* work with `\pstInterFF`?